# How to layout controls and make it resizable

Tags: wpf

I would like to place the controls as listed below in WPF. Please given an example to do the same.

[image: Layout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentRoot">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" .../>
  <TextBox Grid.Column="1" .../>
  <Button Grid.Column="2" .../>
  <Button Grid.Column="3" .../>
</Grid>
```

Assuming that `ContentRoot` is placed directly in your `Window`, it'll inherit it's `Width` and `Height` from the `Window`. Then it'll assign 200px to the 0th column, and 100px each to the 2nd and 3rd columns. And any leftover space will be assigned to the 1st column.

Of course, you can change 200, 100, and 100 to whatever you want.

If needed, add `MinWidth="<value>"` (replace `<value>` with a number) in the 1st `ColumnDefnition` to specify a minimum width that column must have.